# Simple Deform giving wrong orientation

Tags: modifiers

I wanted to make a ribbed edge to a container lid. I started with a plane and subdivided a couple of times and extruded the a couple of sections. I then added the array modifier to give me the desired circumference and then used simple deform to wrap it in a circle. This is what I get.

[image]

I was expecting to have the ribbed edge outward, sort of like a cylinder. What I got was flat. I can't seem to find a combination of settings in array modifier or simple deform to make this work out how I want.

How can I change the orientation of the Simple Deform to make this like a cylinder?

Comment: what happens if you rotate it 90° on the X axis in Edit mode?

Comment: That did it! Thank you. If you want to submit that as a question, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your object, go in *Edit* mode and rotate it 90° on the X axis.